# Is there a way to get Guidewire data model in excel format? @guidewire

Tags: guidewire

Is there a way to get GW Data model in excel format? Data dictionary is currently in html format. Need data dictionary in excel format.

Tried using html but need excel format. Is there any tool to convert html to excel data with data model content?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your use case on what you are trying to do? Data dictionary has data model definitions. There are parsers that can convert html to excel but don’t think it will work out of the box without building a custom parser.

Comment: I would agree with the Abhijay, I don't believe there is a way to do this without creating a custom parser. Can you elaborate on your use case? Maybe if we understood the problem you are trying to solve we could offer other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Use case is to get data dictionary in excel format to be consumed by other systems.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the command line task "gwb genDataMapping" to produce .csv files with all the data model contents included.  There's an option (split=true) that will produce individual files.  The default is one large file with all the contents.

An alternative approach is to use the entityModel.xml file (which is produced during dictionary gen) and bring that into Excel, but that carries along alot of annotations and other information that's problematic to deal with and doesn't add a lot of value when it's not rendered in the default html.

[edit] To be more complete, here's a link to the product documentation (requires login) on the various gwb tasks including the genDataMapping command.  There are several other similar tools like genPcfMapping and gosudoc that can be useful for documenting and sharing configuration details.

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202310/devsetup/developerSetup/topics/r_hn2206669.html?hl=gendatamapping

Comment: Marty for the win. I didn't realize this command line existed to produce csv files of the data model.